# Regex for link in string - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I've been creating script for db migration.
In that case, I must reformatting some old tag that used to modify html to formal html tags.
One of that tag is like this:

```
[link=http://www.example.com/dd/]EXAMPLE TEXT[/link]
```

it supposed to be:

```
<a hre="http://www.example.com/dd/">EXAMPLE TEXT</a>
```

So, i create Regex to match it, but i got no result.

```
$regex = "/(^\[link=)(\W)[\]]$/";
$link_preg_match = preg_match($regex, $string, $match);
print_r($match); // result array()
```

There any solusion for regex so i can get the $match string?
Thanks.

Comment: The backslash is a special character in PHP strings as well as being special in regular expressions, so you have to use a double backslash instead of a single one. (When you want to match a literal backslash in your regex, you need to use 4 backlashes. Pretty annoying.)

Comment: The backslash is treated special on SO too so I gave up trying to write them in my comment :(

Comment: Some instances of backslash don't end up being escapes, so they get included literally. I wouldn't count on it though, because you're likely to accidentally run into cases where it's really an escape.

Comment: Now I'm doubting myself on that statement... maybe the readability advantage of not having a zillion backslashes in your string beats the advantage of guaranteeing that your backslashes aren't going to combine with the following character.

Comment: @NateC-K, actually, i dont bother with the backslases, coz the last character after the link is this "]" caracter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Regex `\[link=(.*)](.*)\[\/link]`

Do like this

```
$input_lines="[link=http://www.example.com/dd/]EXAMPLE TEXT[/link]";
echo preg_replace("~\[link=(.*)](.*)\[\/link]~", "<a hre=$1>$2</a>", $input_lines);
```

[**`DEMO`**](https://eval.in/118511)

**OUTPUT**

```
<a hre=http://www.example.com/dd/>EXAMPLE TEXT</a>
```

Comment: @ailvenge, yep, it's also can't used if the input string like this: [link=http://www.example.com/dd/][EXAMPLE TEXT][/link]

Answer (score 1):

My try on it. Regex:

```
/\[link=(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])\]([a-zA-Z0-9\s._\-\[\]]*)\[\/link]/
```

The code:

```
$regex = "/\[link=(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])\]([a-zA-Z0-9\s._\-\[\]]*)\[\/link]/";
$text = '[link=http://www.example.com/dd/]EXAMPLE TEXT[/link]
[link=http://www.example.com/dd/][EXAMPLE TEXT][/link]';
$replace = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';
$text = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
```

[Also live view on regex](http://regex101.com/r/jY5nZ8)